# "? string:OPTION ?" option tag with angular-chosen

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, jquery-chosen, angular-chosen

I'm trying to create an angular-chosen select menu with a selected option in a Ruby on Rails app. When the page loads and chosen is initialized, the menu does not show the option as selected. When inspecting the HTML, the first option in the menu is
`<option value="? string:AMP ?"></option>`, where AMP is the value of the selected option. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it? Thanks.